# git reset to a local commit head; need to pull from origin keeping local changes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I have a local `feature/branch`. When I pull from a `remote/origin` it's overiding my local changes, when usually it presents me with conflicts from the merge.... How do I set up the local git branch so that I get a conflict report when merging the remote branch and can resolve those conflicts?

UPDATE:

using `git branch -vv` I can see that the branch was merged into the `remote branch origin/master` and has a pull request id. Many changes have been made on top and some of the work on the current `feature/branch` and some changes have been over-written. I moved the `feature/branch` back to a previous commit before it's changes were over-written.

I can see the changes in `git diff master` but I'd like to be able to see the *conflicts* and resolve them in vscode rather than scroll through the terminal output of `git diff master`.

could I detach the `local feature/branch` from the `remote feature/branch` so that git picks up the conflicts on a `git pull origin master`?

Comment: what command are you running to pull?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get latest changes from remote is to first `git fetch` this would bring the changes to your local system. Then check what the changes were using `git diff` and if you want to include those changes AND keep you changes too, use this:

```
git stash -u # u flag is used to include untracked files
git rebase
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a local "master" that has configured to "work against" remote origin and there is one local branch called `feature/branch` created out of master that doesn't have a remove counterpart. To check that (kind of initial check, not directly related to the answer), use:

```
git branch -vv
```

You should see that your local `master` has a remote branch counterpart `origin/master` (listed in square brackets) while `feature/branch` doesn't have any remote branch.

Now in terms of the solution:

You can avoid merges altogether. Assuming your current branch is `feature/branch`:

```
# get the information about the latest changes from "origin". 
# This doesn't change your local filesystem, so you can run it as often as you with 
git fetch origin

# make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes. If you do, stash them or commit if you need, Fo the sake of example, I assume you did three (3) local commits with ids (as if its a sha1) 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

git status

# now when you know that there are no commits and the status is empty, you can:

git rebase origin/master
```

The last command takes the commits that have happened in the origin/master (let's assume, these are commits 'x', 'y' and 'z') and executes a rebase:

The `feature/branch` will look like:

```
'commont-parent-commit` --> 'x' --> 'y' --> 'z' --> 'a*' --> 'b*' --> 'c*'
```

Here `a*` is "logically" the same commit as `a` but having the different sha1.

As you see, there is no merge commits altogether here.

If there were conflicts you'll have to resolve during this process them and then type `git rebase --continue`

Note, there is also a command `git pull --rebase` that you can also use (its a fetch + rebase instead of well-known formula pull = fetch + merge), its a more "compact" way to do the same, but I've found that the way described above is a kind of easier to understand for people starting with rebasing.